# C# (object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) How can I overgive something for the 2nd part?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got the following Code:

```
protected void Name_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

{
    if (e.CommandName == "TextINeed")
    {
        //Some Code
    }

    if (e.CommandName == "SomethingElse")
    {
       //Some Code
    }
}

protected void btn_someButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Name_RowCommand(sender, "TextINeed");
}
```

The Problem i have is with the `Name_RowCommand(sender, "TextINeed");` 
I know that `(sender,` should be right, but how do i make the 2nd part right? I tried a few things but nothing worked so far.

I'm happy about any advice!

Comment: Please come up with a *real* question title that summarizes your problem. A bunch of tags and code isn't a helpful title.

Comment: _"I know that `(sender, =` should be right"_ right in what sense? That's clearly not real code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry my bad. I mean the first part of Name_RowCommand(sender, "TextINeed"); which is (sender,

Comment: Do not call event handlers directly, better extract the content of the method and create a reusable method and call it from both event handlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this is ASP.NET due to the [`GridViewCommandEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).
You can't pass arguments to events directly. Events are triggered. In this case you have to register this event handler, for example on aspx:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" 
  onrowcommand="Name_RowCommand"
  runat="server">

  <columns>
    <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Link" 
      commandname="TextINeed" 
      text="SomeText"/>
   .....
  </columns>

</asp:gridview>
```

If the user now clicks on the link-button the `CommandName` will be `TextINeed`.

If you want to call the code inside of an event handler from another one you should create a method that you can call from both event handlers.

```
private void MyFirstMethod()
{
    //Some Code
}

protected void Name_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "TextINeed")
    {
        MyFirstMethod();
    }
}

protected void btn_someButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyFirstMethod();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try it!

Comment: Or may be the function can take the CommandName as argument ? `MyFirstMethod(e.CommandName);` So that any command can be passed ?

Comment: @Noobie: the command name is irrelevant in this case because the method is only used for the command-name `TextINeed`. OP should use meaningful names of course. So if the method for example deletes a user the name of the method and the command could be `DeleteUser`. Of course a parameter `int UserID` would be useful.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is just an example. They are named diffrent and there is much more code ;)